# Solve equation $(3x^2-2x-1)^2-(6x^2-4x-5)^2+x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quartics

I tried to expand and I had

$27x^4-36x^3-42x^2+35x+24=0$

I don't know how to solve this equation, but I sketch on graph and I have four irrational roots.
Which method I need to use in this equation??

$x_1= \frac{\sqrt{41}}{6}+\frac{1}{2}$

$x_2= -\frac{\sqrt{41}}{6}+\frac{1}{2}$

$x_3= \frac{1-\sqrt{37}}{6}$

$x_4= \frac{1+\sqrt{37}}{6}$

This is roots of equaition, which I tried to find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's denote $a =3x^2-2x-1$, then
$$\begin{align}
&\iff a^2-(2a-3)^2+x =0\\
&\iff a^2 - \left(4a^2-12a+9  \right) + x = 0 \\
&\iff -3a^2+12a-9 + x = 0 \\
&\iff -9a^2+36a-27 + 3x = 0 \\
&\iff -(3a)^2+2\cdot3a\cdot6-6^2+9 + 3x = 0 \\
&\iff -(3a-6)^2+ 3x +9= 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Replace $a =3x^2-2x-1$, then:
$$\begin{align}
(1)&\iff -(3(3x^2-2x-1)-6)^2+ 3x +9= 0 \\
&\iff -(9x^2-6x-9)^2+ 3x +9= 0 \\
&\iff -((3x-1)^2-10)^2+ (3x-1) +10= 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Denote $b=3x-1$, then:
$$\begin{align}
(2)&\iff (b^2-10)^2- (b +10)= 0 \\
&\iff (b^2-10-b)(b^2+b-9)=0 \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
From $(3)$, we deduce that the initial equations has $4$ roots which are roots of the two quadratic equations below:
$$\begin{align}
&(A):b^2-10-b=0 \iff (3x-1)^2-10-(3x-1)=0 \iff \color{red}{x\in\left\{\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{41}}{6}  \right\}}\\
&(B):b^2-9+b=0 \iff (3x-1)^2-9+(3x-1)=0 \iff \color{red}{x\in\left\{\frac{1}{6}\pm\frac{\sqrt{37}}{6}  \right\}}
\end{align}$$

Q.E.D

Comment: I don't really see how you get (3) from previous line.

Comment: @nonuser This problem is at math competition level and so students can use the tricks like
$$\begin{align}
&\iff \left(  (b^2-10)^2 +(b^2-10) +\frac{1}{4} \right)-\left((b^2-10) +\frac{1}{4}+b+10 \right)=0\\
&\iff  \left(b^2-10+\frac{1}{2}  \right)^2 - \left(b+\frac{1}{2}  \right)^2 = 0\\
&\iff (b^2-10+b)(b^2+b-9)=0
\end{align}$$
Of course, to be honest, since decades, I no longer participate any math contest, so I used Wolfram Alpha to guess $(3)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let\begin{align}p(x)&=x^4-\frac43x^3-\frac{14}9x^2+\frac{35}{27}x+\frac89\\&=\frac1{27}\left(27x^4-36x^3-42x^2+35x+24\right).\end{align}Then the reduced form of $p(x)$ is\begin{align}q(x)&=p\left(x+\frac13\right)\\&=y^4-\frac{20}9y^2-\frac1{27}y+\frac{10}9.\end{align}Let $a_0=\frac{10}9$, $a_1=-\frac1{27}$, and $a_2=-\frac{20}9$. Then the [resolvent cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Third_definition) of $q(x)$ is$$r(x)=x^3+2a_2x^2+(a_2^{\,2}-4a_0)y-a_1^{\,2}=x^3-\frac{40}9x^2+\frac{40}{81}x-\frac1{729}.\label{a}\tag1$$If there is a rational number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2$ is a root of \eqref{a}, and if you define$$\beta=\frac12\left(a_2+\alpha^2-\frac{a_1}\alpha\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\gamma=\frac12\left(a_2+\alpha^2+\frac{a_1}\alpha\right),$$then $q(x)=(x^2+\alpha x+\beta)(x^2-\alpha x+\gamma)$. And it turns out that, yes, \eqref{a} has a root which is the square of a rational, since $\frac19$ is a root of \eqref{a} (which can be guessed from the rational root theorem). So, $\alpha=\frac13$, $\beta=-1$, and $\gamma=-\frac{10}9$. Therefore$$q(x)=\left(x^2+\frac13x-1\right)\left(x^2-\frac13x-\frac{10}9\right)$$and all that remains to be done is to compute the roots of these two quadratics and to use the fact that$$p(x)=0\iff q\left(x-\frac13\right)=0.$$

Comment: What's the idea behind the reduced form? Sum of the roots in the original equation is $4/3$ so, we kind of make a change of axes /coordinates, $x\mapsto x-\frac{1}{3}$ so that the sum becomes $0$?

Comment: I would certainly not call it a change of axis, but, yes, the sum of the roots of the reduced form is always $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the OP did wrong [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%283x%5E2-2x-1%29%5E2-%286x%5E2-4x-5%29%5E2%2Bx%3D0). I assume the answer is wrong ultimately as the correct expansion is: $$-27x^4+36x^3+42x^2-35x-24=0$$

Answer (score 1):

I would want to share a solution using the Ferrari's method.

We have the following biquadratic equation:

$$27x^4-36x^3=42x^2-35x-24$$

We attempt to make the LHS a perfect square by adding an $x^2$ term on both sides.

$$(3\sqrt 3x^2)^2-2(3\sqrt3x^2)(2\sqrt 3x)+(2\sqrt3x)^2\\ =54x^2-35x-24$$

Now that we have completed the square on LHS, we have:

$$3(3 x^2-2x)^2=54x^2-35x-24$$

Now we attempt to complete the squares on RHS as well by introducing $\lambda$.

$$3(3 x^2-2x+\lambda)^2\\=54x^2-35x-24+3\{\lambda^2+2\lambda(3x^2-2)\}\\ =\underbrace{(54+18\lambda)}_{=\ a}x^2+\underbrace{(-35-12\lambda)}_{=\ b}x+\underbrace{(3\lambda^2-24)}_{=\ c}$$

Here's how we make the RHS a perfect square:

> We set its discriminant i.e., $b^2-4ac$ to be zero. $$(35+12\lambda)^2-4(54+18\lambda)(3\lambda^2-24)=0$$ This is a cubic equation. $$216\lambda^3+504\lambda^2-2568\lambda-6409=0$$ You could use [Cardano's method](https://www.quora.com/Why-arent-high-school-students-taught-how-to-solve-cubic-equations-algebraically/answer/Sagnik-Saha-82) or apply the rational root theorem to find that $\lambda=-17/6$ is a real solution.
>  The RHS of the original equation now becomes $a\left(x-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2$.

$$\not 3\left(3x^2-2x-\frac{17}{6}\right)^2=\not 3\left(x-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2$$

With difference of squares, you get two quadratics.

$$(3x^2-x-3)\left(3x^2-3x-\frac{16}{6}\right)=0$$

We apply the quadratic formula to solve each of them to get the four roots of our original equation.

Answer (score 0):

After expanding we get:
$$27x^4-36x^3-42x^2+35x+24=0$$
If $t=3x$  then $$\underbrace{t^4-4t^3-14t^2+35t+72}_{p(t)}=0$$
Now we try to find real $a,b,c,d$ such that $$p(t)
 = (t^2+at+b)(t^2+ct+d)
$$
Now we have to solve a following system
\begin{align}
a+c &= -4\\
ac +b+d &=-14\\
ad+bc &= 35\\
bd&=72
\end{align}
If trying to find integer coefficients we get after some trial and error $b=-8$, $d=-9$, $a=-3$ and $c=-1$. The rest is easy.